# PostgreSQL - Clear space on Linux machine

Tags: centos, centos7, storage, postgresql

How can I delete all stored records of my PostgreSQL data in CentOS 7 machine?

Previously I inserted 10 million rows of data with 12 columns, and I ran into storage issues, so I dropped the tables that had 10 million rows of data. But dropping those tables cleared space for only 11GB, and I'm not sure if dropping table is the right way to clear space on CentOS 7 system. The data was previously in `/dev/mapper/centos-root`

`df -h`

[image]

`pvs`, `vgs`, `lvs`

[image]

Moreover, I don't understand How `pvs` and `vgs` says that I only have 4MB of free space, when `df -h` says that I have 11GB available.

Did I clear the space correctly by dropping tables in DB? Or should I take some more advanced methods?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need the `VACUUM` command

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-vacuum.html

> VACUUM reclaims storage occupied by dead tuples. In normal PostgreSQL operation, tuples that are deleted or obsoleted by an update are not physically removed from their table; they remain present until a VACUUM is done. Therefore it's necessary to do VACUUM periodically, especially on frequently-updated tables.